# HTML not picking up value from input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, flask

So basically I am trying to get a value from a table record from its '' found in the record, however my website seems to keep pulling the value from the top input rather than the table records input.

For reference I am getting my table data from a MySQL database and the input value is the ID of the record in the database. My table looks like this:

[image]

I have also set up a basic alert function in my javascript code to test if I can grab the value and the code for that is:

```
function test_id() {
    alert(document.getElementById("testselect").value);
}
```

and my html is:

```
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
            <form id="viewclaim" action="/claim" style="height: 10px;">
                <td>
                    <a onclick="test_id();" href="#">{{item[1]}}</a>
                    <input id="testselect" value="{{item[0]}}"/>
                </td>
            </form>
            <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as my alert seems to keep picking up '1'.

Comment: Each "id" value in a document must be **unique**.

Comment: You're using a loop to generate multiple ids which have to be unique. You could pass the index into `test_id(i)` and use that to find the i-th row's input value. This looks like a pretty brittle way to do whatever you're trying to do. `<form>` is invalid as a child of `<tr>`. Move that into the `<td>`.